# I'm being attacked everywhere I go!

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Every time I try to go near a bigger town in Skyrim I always get attacked by guards and/or villagers. I know that I'm a thief and a vampire (and also a Khajiit) but I don't do anything bad when someone's looking!
I think everything might have started when I tried to feed myself (with blood) in a house in Whiterun. A villager saw me and I quickly ran away from the town, with guards after me, but I didn't kill any of them.

I know that everyone in Whiterun is an Imperial but when I'm near a town with Stormcloaks, they try to kill me too. And if a guard would try to send me to jail now, I would actually go there with no fighting back. But there is no one who's talking to me, only attacking.

What should I do? I can't finish my quests when everyone's attacking me.

Comment: What level of vampirism are you at? Which is to say, what Vampiric Lesser Powers do you have access to?

Comment: Probably lvl 4...

Comment: I haven't fed my Khajiit for a while :/ so... I guess that's it?

Comment: Do you have the Dawnguard DLC installed?

Answer (score 11):

Are you, perhaps a Stage Four Vampire? Stage Four Vampires get attacked **ON SIGHT**, regardless of bounty or anything else.

As per the [UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Vampirism):

> Full vampirism is made up of four distinct stages, starting at stage
>   one and progressing to stage four. You advance one stage for every 24
>   hours you go without feeding on a sleeping NPC. Feeding always returns
>   you to stage one.

~

> Vampires are hated and feared by the general population and stage four
>   vampires will be attacked on sight. The four major joinable factions
>   will not be hostile toward stage four vampires so long as you join
>   before you reach stage four and are not caught feeding on any of their
>   members. With Dawnguard installed, NPCs will only attack you if you
>   are in Vampire Lord form.

Comment: I'm getting a similar thing, except I'm not a vampire (in fact I'm a werewolf but I haven't shifted in a long time), have no bounty, and have nothing stolen in my inventory (I even dropped my blade's sword).

Comment: But you didn't explain how to prevent the 4th stage.

Comment: @Jim It's there in the first quoted paragraph -- "Feeding always returns you to stage one"